# Entity Framework lambda com include retorna collection vazia

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Tenho um select que retorna dados encadeados e os joga em uma ViewModel criada pelo simples motivo de que eu não posso retornar todos os dados da minha tabela, como no exemplo:

```
var data = _context.Forms
.Include(i => i.OrganizationUnit)
.Include(i => i.FormSections)
.Include(i => i.FormSections.Select(p => p.Predecessors))
.Include(i => i.FormSections.Select(p => p.FormSectionSecurities))
.Include(i => i.FormSections.Select(p => p.FormSectionSecurities.Select(x => x.FormSectionSecurityPremission)))
.Include(i => i.FormSections.Select(p => p.FormSectionSecurities.Select(x => x.Role)))
.Include(i => i.FormSections.Select(p => p.FormSectionFields))
.Include(i => i.FormSections.Select(p => p.FormSectionFields.Select(x => x.FormSectionFieldType)))
.Include(i => i.FormSections.Select(p => p.FormSectionFields.Select(x => x.FormSectionFieldType)))
.Include(i => i.FormSections.Select(p => p.FormSectionFields.Select(x => x.List)))
.Include(i => i.FormSections.Select(p => p.FormSectionFields.Select(x => x.List).Select(j => j.ListItems)))
.OrderBy(i => i.Name)
.AsNoTracking()
.Where(i => i.EFormStatus == EFormStatus.Active)
.Select(f => new FormViewModel
{
    Id = f.Id,
    Name = f.Name,
    Description = f.Description,
    EFormStatus = f.EFormStatus,
    Instructions = string.Empty,
    OrganizationUnit = f.OrganizationUnit,
    FormSections = f.FormSections
}).ToList();
```

**f.FormSection** retorna uma collection que tem mais collections dentro, como é possível notar pelos **Includes** por exemplo: **FormSectionFields**.
O problema ocorre justamente no retorno deste "terceiro nível" que vem vazio, mesmo com os includes.
Ocorre também para qualquer coleção que esteja abaixo da coleção **f.FormSection**.

Alguma indicação do que fazer ou o que pode estar errado ?

Abaixo **FormViewModel**

```
public class FormViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OrganizationUnit OrganizationUnit { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
    public EFormStatus EFormStatus { get; set; }
    public ICollection FormSections { get; set; }  
}
```

**ATUALIZADO**

Descarto o uso de joins utilizando Linq (query syntax), pois é necessário que apenas uma linha seja retornada com os objetos encadeados.

Comment: "_[...] um join poderia deixar toda a rotina extremamente mais lenta [...]_". Os `Includes` são traduzidos para _joins_.

Comment: No caso quis dizer joins utilizando LINQ (query syntax), o que alteraria a maneira com que os dados são trazidos do banco. Alterando a pergunta para não causar confusão.

Comment: Você me garante que sua consulta deveria trazer algum registro que possui relacionamento com esse terceiro nível? O include é traduzido para **INNER JOIN**, não **FULL JOIN**. Faça o seguinte, copia a query gerada no IQueryable e tenta executar direto no banco de dados e veja o resultado.

Comment: @GabrielColetta copiando a query gerada no IQueryable o select é executado apenas na primeira tabela, sem nenhum join

Comment: Tem como compartilhar com a comunidade?

Comment: @GabrielColetta consegui resolver o problema utilizando a resposta do Marconcilio Souza. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar vários selects incluindo suas tabelas da seguinte forma.

```
var data = _context.Forms
.Select(f => new 
{
  Forms = f.Forms,
  OrganizationUnit = _context.OrganizationUnit.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrganizationUnitId == f.OrganizationUnitId) // Todo seus ids ... x.OrganizationUnitId == f.OrganizationUnitId
  FormSections = _context.FormSections.Where(x => x.FormSectionsId == f.FormSectionsId) // Todo seus ids ...x.FormSectionsId == f.FormSectionsId  
})
.Select(f => new 
{
   Forms = f.Forms,
   OrganizationUnit = f.OrganizationUnit,
   f.FormSections.Predecessors = _context.Predecessors.Where(x => x.PredecessorsId == f.FormSectionsId) 
   FormSections = f.FormSections,
   // ....  demais campos
})
.AsNoTracking()
.Where(i => i.EFormStatus == EFormStatus.Active)
.Select(f => new FormViewModel
{
    Id = f.Forms.Id,
    Name = f.Forms.Name,
    Description = f.Forms.Description,
    EFormStatus = f.EFormStatus,
    OrganizationUnit = f.OrganizationUnit,
    FormSections = f.FormSections
}).ToList();
```

No final, isso se torna um único select com JOIN, um problema que pode ocorrer no seu caso é que se não existir uma relação entre suas tabelas, as propriedades da sua `FormViewModel` ficara nula.

Por exemplo, se não existir uma relação entre *FormSections e Form* o retorna da propriedade abaixo será `null`.

```
FormSections = _context.FormSections.Where(x => x.FormSectionsId == f.FormSectionsId)
```

Comment: O problema é que no caso do segundo select, onde eu retornaria a terceira coleção, (primeira: Form, segunda: FormSection, terceira: FormSectionFIeld) eu precisaria do Id da segunda (FormSection) para fazer a ligação, porem ela é um IQueryable<> pois é o resultado de um where com o Id da primeira coleção (Form).

Comment: Você precisaria ter outro select ... e assim por diante. até o ultimo nivel.

Comment: consegui implementar o seu exemplo e resolveu o meu problema. muito obrigado!